# Ignore tags already added to the "Ignored Tags" list when adding new ones

Tags: feature-request, tags

When you add tags that should be ignored inside *Prefs*, the search results show all tags (up to six) that it can find. However, it also displays tags that are already on the ignore list:

[image]

For topics that have a lot of tags (like Ubuntu), you end up getting only those tags that you already have ignored, although more are available you might want to ignore.

Comment: I've tried to come up with something -- does that make sense? :P (Still, very valid feature-req)

Comment: Thanks, that sound's better! It's not Monty Python anymore, so I will also remove the first sentence.

Comment: The same thing applies to removing favourite tag suggestions for tags that are already favourites (I have this problem with the OSX tags...)